# Cut hex addresses without having them expanded into text

Tags: bash, cut, head

I'm getting a window id with this command and storing it into a variable

```
id=$(xdo id -n "piper" || xdo id -N "Piper")
echo $id
0x04000007 0x04000001
```

However, when I try to use **cut** or **head** to get only the first address, they convert the hex value to text. For example:

```
id=$(id | cut -f1 -d' ')
echo $id
uid=1007(user)
```

I've looked into both cut and head but haven't found any way to make them not (expand?) the hex value. I'd like to get the first value as it is.

Answer (score 1):

`id` (a command) is not the same as `${id}` (a variable reference); and `id` does not return the same thing as `xdo ... || xdo ...`

Assuming the variable `id` has your hex codes, and said codes are separated by a space, you can use parameter expansion to pull the first hex code, eg:

```
$ echo ${id%% *}
0x04000007

## or

$ echo ${id// */}
0x04000007

## or

$ echo ${id// *}
0x04000007
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not actually what's happening here. You are actually just calling the program `id`, which returns your users group ids. You need to echo the `$id` field. Try:

```
id1=$(echo $id | cut -f1 -d' ')
echo $id1
```